# Forwarding web browser HTTP requests

Tags: http-proxy

I'm trying to implement a client application that would receive HTTP requests from web browser, and then forward the requests to a server.

1) Client waits for a web browser request on port 10080

2) Client forwards the request to a server

I am struggling with the first part. Do I need to redirect HTTP requests from port 80 to my client ? How could I do that ?

Comment: in other words: you want to implement a http proxy?

Comment: I thought the web browser would directly forwards the request to the server with a http proxy, am i wrong ?

Comment: If you have set a http proxy in your browser, the connection is established to that address. the proxy server reads out the `HOST:` header and connects to that address. Does that answer your question?